# On an HP proliant DL380 G9 with P840 RAID10 vs mdadm RAID10

Tags: mdadm, raid-10

On an HP proliant DL380 g9 with smartarray P840, I have a ubuntu 17.04 vm acting as an ownCloud server.  Does it make difference if I use a HW RAID10 instead of mdadm RAID10? Is there any data that favors one over the other in terms of speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a RAID 10 the speed difference between the two should be negligible if their is any at all because their is no parity.

If you run a RAID6 in the future, you might take a performance hit for full rate internal data transfers but not external (cloud) tranfers.

Further, the HW raid does have the disadvantage of being proprietary and causing the headache of needing to replace your controller with a compatible controller if the controller fails.

On our Dell Server, we setup the drives each as single drive RAID 0's exposing them to the host as raw devices, then we used MDRAID1 for the host and MDRAID10 for the data.

Your controller might allow the drives to be "passed" through to the host, our controller would not allow that.

Point is, I default to MDRAID for a combination of performance, reliability, robustness, and simplicity unless there is some odd configuration or performance mark that we are trying to work with.

Comment: This was my feeling about this smartarray after a couple of days working with it.  So i am gladi got some validation from you.  i wish i can put numbebrs next to this, but this will do for now. one thing thing though, i think one has to have the P840 enabled since it takes care of the thermal readings and the adjustments of fan speed... it is scary loud when it is off.... i need to read about this one and see if HBA mode is quite enough.